# Should app developer have to explicitely allow enabling tracing via the app.config file?

Tags: .net, logging, configuration

Let's have a class, which is able to log it's operations to a trace file. This trace file might include sensitive data (like usernames or hostnames).

Tracing can be enabled in code like this:

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass();
// turn on tracing for this instance
instance.LogWriter = new FileLogWriter("path_to_trace_file");
```

It should also be possible to enable tracing by editing the configuration file like this:

```
<myComponent>
  <logWriter name="FileLogWriter">
      <param name="File" value="path_to_trace_file"/>
  </logWriter>
</myComponent>
```

**Should developer who is using the class be required to explicitly allow turning tracing on in the config file?**

**Option 1: Enabling tracing in config should be possible by default**

If developer does nothing the tracing can be turned on by editing configuration file.

- good: Diagnostic can be turned on by admin even if developer did not think about it.
- bad: User/admin can turn on tracing and easily get access to sensitive data. (Malicious user would be able to get those data even without tracing but would require more advanced tools like using a packet capture software or attaching a debugger to a running process. Disabled tracing would only make it harder)
- bad: component must read configuration file every time, which can scare paranoid devs/admins.

**Option 2: Developer must allow turning tracing on in config**

By default the `logWriter` section in config file is ignored. Developer have to either enable it from code:

```
instance.LogWriter = LogWriterHelper.ReadFromConfig()
```

or by setting an assembly level attribute:

```
[assembly: Component.Configuration.XmlLogWriterConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

- bad: Admin will not be able to get a trace from a file when developer is not available.
- bad: A bit more work for turning tracing on.
- good: Tracing can be turned on/off per class instance.
- good: Tracing can be still turned on for all instances in the assembly.
- good: Class reads configuration file only when developer explicitly requests it.

What do you think? Which of those two options are better?

Answer (score 0):

Why not a best of both worlds approach - your first option but only allow logging of non-sensitive data?

**UPDATE**
Extrapolating from your use case in the comment, if I was an admin, I wouldn't be happy with your first approach as-is. I can't see logging of non-sensitive data as being an issue though.

Your second option requires a "dev" build of the component, again not exactly ideal. You could always separate this into a separate "debug proxy" component, which all calls to\from your component go through. It would only be deployed when extra debugging is needed.

Comment: I was going to say "Option 3:  Enabling tracing in config should be possible by default but dev can explicitly turn off tracing" but that's basically what cristobalito wrote

Comment: Because sensitive data are often needed for diagnostics. The MyClass is a communication component and in most verbose level it logs raw data of (some) packets. It would be hard do diagnose and fix connection/login problems without knowing things like hostnames, port, usernames or content of packets received from the server.

Comment: Well, why not a further iteration: by default, do as I suggest - allows you to deploy on the clients side and gain a good level of information, while still maintaining the clients privacy. 

If further information is required, then a custom diagnostic build (i.e. your option two) can be produced. Bit of hassle as it involves two potential deployments, but from your description, it's going to be hard to avoid this in any case.

Comment: reaction to update: The second option does not require a special 'dev' build of the component. It requires a special 'dev' build of the application which uses the component. There is only one version of the component itself.